# How to get the device memory or application size(Memory taken in Internal storage) using Appium

Tags: automation, appium-android, android-uiautomator, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have to get the details such as CPU, Memory(RAM), Battery, Startup time, App Size. Im able to get other things except App Size using Appium. Someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Appium is not capable to perform this for you. However, you can check the memory usage in Android using adb:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.android.systemui
```

Which returns something like this:

```
Applications Memory Usage (in Kilobytes):
Uptime: 433213978 Realtime: 631179899

** MEMINFO in pid 1541 [com.android.systemui] **
                   Pss  Private  Private  SwapPss     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap   106880   106780        0    73228   196200   182430    13769
  Dalvik Heap    35655    35636        0      217    40741    20371    20370
 Dalvik Other     3347     3344        0      112                           
        Stack       56       56        0       16                           
       Ashmem        4        0        0        0                           
    Other dev       18        0       16        0                           
     .so mmap     2998      164      352      499                           
    .jar mmap      669        0      248        0                           
    .apk mmap    17904        0    13620        0                           
    .ttf mmap      372        0      180        0                           
    .dex mmap    10041       16    10020       20                           
    .oat mmap     3848        0       84        0                           
    .art mmap     1641     1364        0      123                           
   Other mmap       64       12       24        0                           
   EGL mtrack   106434   106434        0        0                           
    GL mtrack    55564    55564        0        0                           
      Unknown     1952     1948        0     1565                           
        TOTAL   423227   311318    24544    75780   236941   202801    34139
```

For iOS, my currently limited toolchain doesn't help much. You may have luck using Instruments, for which you can find here a command-line reference, but I haven't tried that: https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/devb14ffaa5